# Backbone.model.save sending the whole backbone.model in request body

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

when i `backbone.Model.save()`,
it sends the whole model data (each and every property even when it has not been modified) in the body of the request.

i want to send in the body only properties of the model, that has been modified.

I am doing :

```
here.model.save( 
                  {field:params.value},
                  { patch: true,
                    error: function() {
                      d.reject('Server Error..!');
                    },
                    success: function() {
                      d.resolve();
                    }
                  }
                );
```

but patch:true doesn't work.

what is the error? and how to resolve?

Comment: I don't think `patch` is what you're looking for… I think `patch` has something to do with older versions of IE. Also, yes when you call `save` on model, it will pass along every attributes it has. If you only want to sync modified attributes then override `toJSON` for that model. You can even patch `Backbone.Model` if you want to…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`patch` works only for already created models. In case if your model is new it wouldn't work.

#### How to fix it:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model();
var attributesToSave = {};
model.save(null, {attrs:attributesToSave});
```

Comment: And saved on server? Because dynamically created model on client and created on server is not the same.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Please provide more code - model itself and model initialization